# Spring Boot starter based on another starter with default configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to do my own spring boot starter based on `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-actuator`. It is meant to provide easier integration with platform used in our company. In my starter I need some custom configuration for actuator which is normally done in `application.yml` file and it looks like this:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure.include:
        - 'prometheus'
        - 'health'
      base-path: '/_meta'
      path-mapping:
        health: healthcheck
        prometheus: metrics
  metrics:
    web:
      server.request.autotime.percentiles: 0.50,0.75,0.90,0.99
      client.request.autotime.percentiles: 0.50,0.75,0.90,0.99
```

But if I put configuration file in my starter it is overriden by config from actual application. So, the question is how can I provide custom configuration for actuator (or any other spring properties actually) in my starter?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I posted this question, but if someone came across same problem, here is solution I used:

create properties file with defaults in my starter (src/main/resources/starter-defaults.properties):

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.jmx.enabled=false
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude=*
management.endpoint.beans.enabled=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=prometheus,health,info,g2aStandardHealth
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/_meta
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=healthcheck
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.prometheus=metrics
management.metrics.web.server.request.autotime.percentiles=0.50,0.75,0.90,0.99
management.metrics.web.client.request.autotime.percentiles=0.50,0.75,0.90,0.99
```

Add class (also to my starter):

```
public class DefaultConfigLoader implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultConfigLoader.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("starter-defaults.properties"));
            event.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(new PropertiesPropertySource("starter-defaults", props));
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            logger.error("Unable to read defaults", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

And that's all. Default configuration will be loaded during application startup.